# jquery jtable Checkbox is not showing in the list

Tags: jquery, jquery-jtable

actually i want to display Checkbox in the list for Boolean values from database

```
OriginatingLocation: {
   title: 'Originating Location',
   width: '30%',
   list: true,
   type:checkbox,
   create: false,
   edit: false
},
```

Comment: Please, post your code.

Comment: Please explain better

Comment: please some body has to help me

Comment: i want to display checkbox for originating Location field . that was a boolean field in db . it contains true or false values.if true i want to display in the list with checkbox with checked otherwise display empty check box

Comment: that code is not working

Answer (score 5):

It seems like you dont want to add or edit the record then it is very easy.
jTable damo page (PagingAndSorting demo) having `display:` function, You can see it [here](http://jtable.org/ApiReference/FieldOptions#fopt-display). Also you can find more about jTable [ApiReference](http://jtable.org/ApiReference) here.
Below code may help you

```
OriginatingLocation: {
    title: 'Originating Location',
    width: '30%',
    list: true,
    display: function (data) {
            if (data.record.OriginatingLocation == true)
            {
                return '<input type="checkbox" checked>';
            }
            else
            {
                return '<input type="checkbox">';
            }
    },
create: false,
edit: false
},
```

Here `OriginatingLocation` is **Boolean** field.